# How to return values from nested promise?

Tags: node.js, redis, promise, bluebird

I have a set of IDs of movies in Redis:  `[1,2,3,4]` and a set of hashes with the actual data. Now, I want to fetch all the movie data for the IDs in once.

I am trying to use bluebird promisses, but I got stuck. So far, I have:

```
  function allMovies() {
    var movies, movieIds;
    return client.smembersAsync('movies.ids').then(function(ids) {
      movieIds = ids;
      movies =  _.map(movieIds, function(id) {
         var movie;
         return client.hmgetAsync("movies:" + id, 'title', 'description', 'director', 'year').done(function(data) {
           movie = data;
           return {
                 title: data[0], 
                 description: data[1], 
                 director: data[2],
                 year: data[3]
               };
          });
          return movie;
        });
    })
```

The problem is from what I try, that I always get back a new promise, while I am just interested in a JSON after all operations have finished.

Anyone here can shed some light into this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In bluebird, there is a more sugary way of doing this:

```
function allMovies() {
    return client.smembersAsync("movies.ids").map(function(id){
        return client.hmgetAsync( "movies:" + id, 'title', 'description', 'director', 'year');
    }).map(function(data){
        return {
            title: data[0],
            description: data[1],
            director: data[2],
            year: data[3]
        };
    });
}
```

Comment: { isFulfilled: true,
  isRejected: false,
  fulfillmentValue: [],
  rejectionReason: undefined }

Comment: @poseid how are you using the `allMovies()` function? If you are using it like `allMovies().then(function(movies){console.log(movies)})` then that's a serious bug. However, it really looks like you are using it like `console.log(allMovies())` - the function doesn't return the movies it returns a promise for movies.

Comment: both result in that empty Array:ma.then(function(m) { console.log(m) }) and ma.allMovies() with ma the promise from allMovies. I'll file a bug in Github.

Comment: thanks - https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/20#issuecomment-26675418

Answer (score 1):

If Bluebird is consistent with Q on this issue, it’s just a matter of taking your array of promises and turning them into a promise for the array of results. Note the addition of `Q.all` to your example, the return inside the handler, and the use of `then` instead of `done` to chain the movie promise.

```
function allMovies() {
    var movies, movieIds;
    return client.smembersAsync('movies.ids').then(function(ids) {
        movieIds = ids;
        movies =  _.map(movieIds, function(id) {
           var movie;
           return client.hmgetAsync("movies:" + id, 'title', 'description', 'director', 'year')
           .then(function(data) {
               return {
                   title: data[0], 
                   description: data[1], 
                   director: data[2],
                   year: data[3]
                };
            });
        });
        return Q.all(movies);
    })
```